# Error with npm test but not mocha test node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, mocha.js

I am working with node.js and mocha unit testing and I want to be able to run the test command through npm. When I run mocha test in my tests folder, the test runs sucessfully. However, when I run npm test, the test gives me an error.

[image]

Here is a snippet from my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./tests/test.js"
  },
```

Anyone know why the npm test would give me an error but mocha test runs just fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `./tests/test.js`, because it's executable, it tries to execute the file using your shell.

I think that node should be executing the file and not your default shell.

I think you could change it to `node ./tests/test.js` or to `mocha test`